# Configuring Grub to dual-boot across two discs?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I'd like to have my Windows 7 on one disc and my Ubuntu on a second disc. Windows 7 is already installed- how should I go about configuring grub to treat the two discs with two operating systems? Instead of "install alongside Windows 7" should I choose the custom partition management option during installation?

Answer (score 0):

there was a thread about this in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1558804)

the solution was:

> Found a different solution:
>   I added "(hd1) /dev/sdb" to /boot/grub/device.map and ran update-grub.
>   This adds to operating systems on the second drive to GRUB, which works just as well.